# comparing and pushing array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

array1:

```
 [{"Attribute1":"Apple","Attribute2":"jacob.nelson@cognizant.com"}]
```

array2:

```
[{"Attribute1":"orange"}]`
```

I want to replace the value of "Attribute1" in array1 to value of "Attribute1" in array2.
My output should be like

```
[{"Attribute1":"orange","Attribute2":"jacob.nelson@cognizant.com"}]
```

I'm new to javascript.Am stuck here.Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If both arrays are defined as above, are you wanting to do this?:  array1[0].Attribute1 = array2[0].Attribute1;

Comment: There's no function that will do this for you. You'll have to loop and compare the objects manually.

Comment: In case it's not apparent, you should realize that both of your arrays currently only have one item in it - an object, which contains a set of members.  Do you really need an array, or is the object sufficient?  (In other words, are you looking for `array1[0].Attribute1 = array2[0].Attribute1` as @DavidFleeman suggested, or do you really just want `obj1.Attribute1 = obj2.Attribute1`?)  Frequently in JavaScript, all you need is the dynamic object.

Comment: Relevant merge thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: Actually i need a array not an object

Comment: What is the big picture of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: using [Object.extend](https://gist.github.com/rlemon/e42d47195a7f88051c17) you can `arr1 = Object.extend(arr1, arr2)` for your desired results. However this is probably overkill.

Comment: @user2882721, didn't your question's title sound like 'comparing and pushing array of OBJECTS in javascript'? Now you say you don't need objects..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you showed us is JSON objects representation.

In this case you have an array of objects, so if you do next:

```
>>ar=[{"Attribute1":"Apple","Attribute2":"jacob.nelson@cognizant.com"}]
[Object]
```

This says that you have one object in an array, then yoou have to get it:

```
>>obj=ar[0]
Object {Attribute1: "Apple", Attribute2: "jacob.nelson@cognizant.com"}
```

Then if you need to replace something in objects, you have to treat them like OBJECTS!

```
>>ar2=[{"Attribute1":"orange"}]
>>obj2=ar2[0]
>>obj1.Attribute1=obj2.Attribute1
```

And that's all!

**TIP** if you have many objects, loop over them:

```
>>objects_array=[
        {"Attribute1":"Apple","Attribute2":"jacob.nelson@cognizant.com"}, 
        {"Attribute1":"Cucumber","Attribute2":"asd@qwe.com"}
    ]
[Object, Object]
>>for obj in objects_array {
   obj.Attribute1='Whatever'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably overkill for this single case, however here it is:

Using [Object.extend](https://gist.github.com/rlemon/e42d47195a7f88051c17)

```
// adds Object.extend if it does not already exist
if (typeof Object.extend !== 'function') {
    Object.extend = function (d /* DESTINATION */, s /* SOURCE */) {
        for (var k in s) {
            if (s.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                var v = s[k];
                if (d.hasOwnProperty(k) && typeof d[k] === "object" && typeof v === "object") {
                    Object.extend(d[k], v);
                } else {
                    d[k] = v;
                }
            }
        }
        return d;
    };
}
```

you can get the desired results by doing this:

```
var arr1 = [{"Attribute1":"Apple","Attribute2":"jacob.nelson@cognizant.com"}],
    arr2 = [{"Attribute1":"orange"}];
arr1 = Object.extend(arr1, arr2);
>> [{"Attribute1":"orange","Attribute2":"jacob.nelson@cognizant.com"}]
```

But like it is mentioned in the comments; if this is the only case, do this by hand.